# Always entering a While loop with method inside

Tags: loops, while-loop

here is my problem from my last night's coding.
It was working fine until something happened and every time is entering the while loop:

```
public void cartFill() throws IOException {
    print.selectYourPhoneType();
    phone.setType(print.upToLowerWord(reader.readLine()));

    while (phone.getType() != "Smartphone" || phone.getType() != "Cellphone"){
        tryAgain();
    }                                                                                    
    void tryAgain() throws IOException {
    print.wrongInput();
    print.selectYourPhoneType();
    phone.setType(reader.readLine());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If phone.getType() returns a String. This function will always run into the `while` loop.

Your while OR conditions are

1. `phone.getType()` not equals to "Smartphone"
2. `phone.getType()` not equals to "Cellphone"

So if `phone.getType()` returns "Smartphone"  It is true for case 2 condition because it is not "Cellphone. Likewise if it returns "Cellphone".

Instead:

1. Tune your OR condition. `while( !(phone.getType() == "Smartphone" || phone.getType() == "Cellphone") )`
2. Check if `phone.getType()` does not exist in list `["Smartphone", "Cellphone"]`.

Comment: so I should create two single while loops for escaping all the wrong inputs?
or put them into a list of Strings and try the .contains method?

Comment: this one -> put them into a list of Strings and try the .contains method with ! operator.  So it means that repeat loop if phone.getType() is not in list.
If you do not add ! operator, it would translate as repeat loop if phone.getType() is in list.

Comment: it worked with a List.
Thanks <3
It was strange that the while loop was working, also, but something happened... :D